# Activate Windows File Explroer

Tags: autohotkey

I thought this was easy but it seems not. I just want to activate File Explorer this way:
`WinActivate ahk_exe Explorer.EXE`
But it won't work. It seems that all others work just fine:

```
WinActivate ahk_exe chrome.exe ; works
WinActivate ahk_exe notepad++.exe ; works
WinActivate ahk_exe OUTLOOK.EXE ; works
```

I also tried

```
WinActivate "ahk_class CabinetWClass"
```

Comment: It's probably activating the taskbar, which is also from `EXPLORER.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach works, but you shouldn't use quotes. Try this:

```
WinActivate ahk_class CabinetWClass
```

You can also make it an expression and then you must use quotes, like this:

```
WinActivate % "ahk_class CabinetWClass"
```